# ¿Es posible usar un operador de comparación para varios valores?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, comparaciones

Estaba creando una función que pudiera detectar si un número romano estaba bien escrito o no. Para crear esa función he necesitado usar muchos `if` y quería saber si es posible simplificar este tipo de expresiones:

```
if ((x == y || x == z || x == w) && x < a)
```

por algo así como:

```
if ( x == (y || z || w) && x < a)
```

Esto me ayudaría muchísimo ya que la "x" suele ser una expresión muy larga como `num[i] + num[i + 1]` además de tener que compararla con muchas otras variables. Lo que quiero hacer es usar solo una vez la "x" i compararla con "y", "z" y "w" de una tirada sin tener que reescribir `x == n` continuadamente detrás de `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar un statement [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```js
switch (x) {
  case w:
  case y:
  case z:
    //lo que quieres hacer
  default:
    // ninguna de las opciones
```

`if ( x == (y || z || w) && x < a)` esto no va a funcionar. Si prestas atención al tipo de la comparación, la expresión (y || z || w) devuelve un valor booleano y lo compararias con la x. Si alguna variable tiene valor, la comparación devuelve verdadero, y luego compararias `x == true`. Si x tiene valor, esto va a devolver verdadero, incluso si ninguna de las variables tiene el mismo valor que x.

Otra forma de hacerlo podría ser con un Array y el método `includes`:

```
if ([w, y, z].includes(x)) {
 // etc...
}
```

Comment: ¿Este mètodo se puede aplicar con otros operadores que no sean de comparación? para hacerlo con el operador `!=` simplemente puse `!` pero no se si es posible hacerlo con otros operadores como `<`...

Comment: el primero, `switch`, no. Pero usando arrays es posible encontrar formas para hacer multiples comparaciones.. Por ejemplo `![w, y, x].includes(x)` para desigualdad... o `[w, y, z].every( (num) => num > x) ` para verificar que x es menor que todos los elementos